# Create month abbrevation in german - Perl

Tags: perl, date-format

I want yesterdays date in perl in a specific format.

My Script:

```
use DateTime qw( );
use Date::Parse;
use Date::Language;
   
my $lang = Date::Language->new('German'); 

    my $yday_date =
       DateTime
          ->now( time_zone => 'local' )
          ->set_time_zone('floating')
          ->truncate( to => 'day' )
          ->subtract( days => 1 )
          ->strftime('%b%d');
          
            print $lang ->time2str($yday_date)
```

**What I get:**

Dec08

**What I need**

Dez08

Does anyone know what the issue is?
Any answer is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass the `time` to the language object together with the formatting string.

Example:

```
use DateTime qw( );
use Date::Parse;
use Date::Language;

my $lang = Date::Language->new('German');

my $yday_date =
   DateTime
      ->now( time_zone => 'local' )
      ->set_time_zone('floating')
      ->truncate( to => 'day' )
      ->subtract( days => 1 )
      ->epoch;

print $lang->time2str('%b%d', $yday_date) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 6):

You're calling [Date::Language](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Language)'s `time2str` with a literal string, not with a format string plus a time in second since 1970.

But you don't need Date::Language at all, [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) can handle localization by itself.

Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;

my $yday_date =
   DateTime
      ->now( time_zone => 'local', locale => 'de' )
      ->set_time_zone('floating')
      ->truncate( to => 'day' )
      ->subtract( days => 1 )
      ->strftime('%b%d');
          
print $yday_date;
```

**Edit:** if you need a string like `Dez08` instead of `Dez.08`, I wouldn't add another module to the mix, but just solve it by removing the `.`.  Something like:

```
$yday_date =~ s/\.//;
```

Comment: Thank you! I did this too but the result is 'Dez.08'. I just need it without the dot. I found this but does not know how use that: https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DateTime-Locale/lib/DateTime/Locale/de_DE.pod#Abbreviated-(stand-alone)1

Comment: I would just remove the `.` instead of adding another module.  I edited the answer to suggest that.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't what I would do to solve this, but it does answer how to use the [DateTime::Locale module](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DateTime-Locale/lib/DateTime/Locale/de_DE.pod#Abbreviated-(stand-alone)1) linked in [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65217736/create-month-abbrevation-in-german-perl#comment115298492_65218111) on [mscha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65218111/1331451).

DateTime::Locale::de_DE is one of the packages that provides the data for the formatter to format the date into a locale. It has different methods that provide that data. The one you have linked to in particular (*Abbreviated (stand-alone)*
) is used when a certain component of the date is used on its own, rather than in a form. There's a second block called [*Abbreviated (format)*](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DateTime-Locale/lib/DateTime/Locale/de_DE.pod#Abbreviated-(format)1) that has the dots.

These are used by methods on the DateTime::Locale::* objects of similar names. We want `month_stand_alone_abbreviated`, but when called, it returns a list of month names.

Because the one you want to use is not to be used in an actual format string, which is what `strftime` would do, we can do it ourselves. [You can implement your own DateTime::Format](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Builder) that does exactly what you need, for this very specific case.

**Disclaimer:** I don't know if this is the right approach, and it's probably incomplete and will not work in any but this very specific use-case. It also won't parse incoming dates properly. I didn't bother looking up how that works. It needed to have a parser to work, so I wrote one that is probably wrong.

```perl
package DateTime::Format::GermanOhnePunkt;
use DateTime::Format::Builder (
    parsers => {
        parse_date => [ {
            regex => qr/^(...)(..)$/,
            params => [qw(month day)]
        }
        ]});

sub format_datetime {
    my ($self, $dt) = @_;

    my @months = $dt->locale->month_stand_alone_abbreviated;
    return sprintf '%s%02d', $months[0][$dt->month - 1], $dt->day;
}
```

All this does is fetch the DateTime::Locale out, get the list of months, and then return the string you wanted. It's very naive, but it works.

Use it like this:

```perl
my $yday_date =
   DateTime
      ->now( 
        time_zone => 'local', 
        locale    => 'de_DE', 
        formatter => DateTime::Format::GermanOhnePunkt->new,
      )
      ->set_time_zone('floating')
      ->truncate( to => 'day' )
      ->subtract( days => 1 );

print $yday_date;
```

This will output `Dez08` today at the time of writing.

Also see [the DateTime::Format::Builder tutorial](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DateTime-Format-Builder/lib/DateTime/Format/Builder/Tutorial.pod).

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. I will try it and give you my feedback